# Can I utilise JPA 2.1 @Converter with DB entities?

Tags: jpa

Maybe, I'm a bit wrong, however, I'm trying to refactor my code right now via making use of @Converter annotation from JPA 2.1 to out-source the attribute-to-dbdata converting from the POJO class to a separate class. I'm mainly utilising a custom transformation for storing a kind of JSON blob into a database column. I have several cases, where I need to rely on the order of child entities, i.e., I store the set of utilised child entities in a many-to-many table to keep the relationship between the items and, furthermore, the order in a JSON array that just keeps the child entity identifiers (to keep the order). Then I have a resolving mechanism that keeps both sides always up-to-date, i.e., the db-data (string) will be converted to a (ordered) list of child entities (that are also stored in the DB and available via the set of child entities (many-to-many relationship).

So right now I'm wondering, whether I can handle this with a @Converter (AttributeConverter) implementation, since I'll require the set of child entities to resolve the db-data (string) to a (ordered) list of child entities (i.e. the "convertToEntityAttribute" method implementation)? Or whether I need to rely on my (a bit cumbersome) mechanism in the POJO class to convert between both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AttributeConverter is for simple types only, not collections/maps, and as such provides a mapping between a java type and a database column. Some JPA implementations may allow mapping to multiple columns (I know the JPA implementation I use does, DataNucleus JPA, and some others may also allow it), but I doubt you'll get one that allows mapping to some other table entirely.

Better to look at your entity mappings and consider creating a dummy entity for this information somehow

Comment: thanks a lot for clarification. Ok, then I'm fine with my current, working solution ;) (I don't need yet another entity ...)